# Should OP edit their question or leave feedback on an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments, editing-help

Recently, I came across [a question which the OP edited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54739074) in order to leave feedback about [an answer which didn't work for them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54739074) (where they also left a comment). They included the errors they got in their questions, see [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54739074/revisions).

My question is: Should that happen? Should OPs edit their questions to say that they have tried the existing answers and they didn't work, including the errors they got, or just leave a comment in the respective answer?

In my opinion, they must leave a comment in the answerer's post. The code may contain a typographical error or it might be an OP's (accidental) fault. After an edit to the answer, it might work.

But, if this clearly didn't work (no typos, e.t.c.), they should include it in the answer like:

> Additionally, I have also tried:
>
> ```
> some code here
> what the OP tried
> ```
>
> But I got:
>
> > Some random output

What are your opinions?

Comment: Of course they should do so to improve their questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what they should do?

Comment: Maybe both things, leave a comment at the answer and additionally edit their question to clarify.

Comment: Without changing the original sense of the question. Of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general principle for questions is that they should be... well, *questions*. Not blogs, wikis, or proxies for chat rooms. Questions should be read like a coherent whole; like the third draft of a short story, they should be *cleaned up* during an edit, not have additional information merely tacked onto the end.

Putting @mentions, other symbols, EDITs and replies to things posted as answers are all warning signs that a question has been devolved from an actual question into a news article or forum post.

That said, we ask for **prior effort** at Stack Overflow, so since we make the ask, there shouldn't be anything wrong with providing that information in the question itself.

Comment: An answer like that ("See all those warning messages you ignored? Try redoing the thing") is also, in itself, a sign of a problematic question.